# Mongodb updating a field which is indexed as 2dsphere

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I got why we can't update primary keys which are indexed as unique. But I couldn't find why I am not able update the geolocation data which is indexed as **2dsphere**. I am trying to update geolocation data in a collection but the update will not happen unless I remove the location part from **$set** of the query. Is this how it works or Am I doing anything wrong? Please help if there is another method for doing this. Thanks.
This are my indexes

```
     { key: { phone: 1 }, unique: true },
     { key: { slug: 1 } },
     { key: { location: "2dsphere" } },
     { key: { name: "text" } }
```

Comment: Add the update logic/code snippet too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this and it worked..

```
db.places.insert(
   {
      loc : { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.97, 40.77 ] },
      name: "Central Park",
      category : "Parks"
   }
)


db.places.createIndex( { loc : "2dsphere" } )


db.places.update({ "name" : "Central Park"},{
 $set: { loc : { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.88, 43.78 ] } }
 })
```

This updates the record and cause no issue.

```
db.getCollection('places').find({})
```

output:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f304f3150aad1afe92efb72"),
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            -73.88, 
            43.78
        ]
    },
    "name" : "Central Park",
    "category" : "Parks"
}
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to create the "loc" field at the creation of the document ?

Comment: Because I tried adding dummy values at creation and tried updating and it worked.

Comment: > Is it mandatory to create the "loc" field at the creation of the document?
......
Nope.It's not necessary to create the loc field at the creation of the document.

Comment: I resolved it. Something was wrong with my indexes. Had to delete and create indexes and it worked. Thanks for the clarification.